# Getting a JSON object out of a backbone.js collection

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js

I am geting a JSON feed from a RESTful API.  The JSON I get from the server is an object with 2 different arrays of objects.  I am breaking that JSON into a couple different Backbone collections which works fine.  My backbone objects looks like this:

```
Document = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        did: '',
        fields: []
    }
});

Documents = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Document
});
```

The objects themselves are fine, but I am trying to use Handlebars.js for templating and have found the must take an object, not an array.  When I take my Documents object and do a .toJSON(), it seems to return an Array, not an object. So the raw JSON i get from the server looks like:

```
{
"Docs":[
    {"Fields":[{"ID":59,"VAL":""},{"ID":157,"VAL":""}],"Id":4143},
    {"Fields":[{"ID":59,"VAL":""},{"ID":69,"VAL":""}],"Id":4142}
]
}
```

But once it gets pushed into the backbone collection then pulled back out for the handlebars handoff, it looks like this:

```
[
    {"Fields":[{"ID":59,"VAL":""},{"ID":157,"VAL":""}],"Id":4143},
    {"Fields":[{"ID":59,"VAL":""},{"ID":69,"VAL":""}],"Id":4142}
]
```

How can I get backbone to give me back the object rather than just an array with the contents of the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

backbone gives you an array from a collection because that is what the collection holds -- an array of models.

I'm not sure I'm clear on exactly what you're trying to do, but it looks like all you actually need is to have the server receive a document that looks like:

```
{
    "Docs": docCollection.toJSON()
}
```

If this is the case, I'd just override the toJSON method on your Documents class to do something like:

```
toJSON: function() {
    return {"Docs": Backbone.Collections.prototype.toJSON.apply(self, arguments)};
}
```

This should pretty much do what you say you want, at least as I understand it.

Comment: This was on the right track.  The following worked for me.   

 Documents = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  toModdedJSON: function(){
   return {"Docs": this.toJSON()};
  }
 });
Calling toJSON from within the overloaded method was causing recursion issues.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Backbone collections don't play as nicely as they should with handlebars. Since it returns a plain JavaScript object you have to reference it as such.

Try:

```
{{#each []}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ this.title }}</td>
    <td>{{ this.start }}</td>
    <td>Invited</td>
    <td>Confirmed</td>
    <td>Edit</td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```